# How to fetch data only after calling the component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a component(modal) which I am calling from two different components on clicking it but I fetches data while my two of the parent components load.
I want it to be inside my component(modal) and need to fetch data only after the modal is called.

```
const User = ({ A, B,C }) => {

  const { isLoading, isError, data } = useUserQuery(C);
.........................
.........................
..................
........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your modal is `mounting` even before it is shown to the user, and on button click you make it only visually appear?

React-query will fetch when you `mount` the component, so I'd say the modal should only mount once you click the button. Otherwise, I think you'd have to disable the query via the `enabled` option and enable it once you show the Modal, but that's a bit lengthy...

Comment: Yes
Whenever I load my previous component it shows "loading user data" at the bottom and is already fetched before opening the button onClick.
What should I do here?

Comment: mount your modal only when the user opens it, not before that.